# Javascript HTTP request

Tags: javascript, httprequest

I have this function and when i run it in the console it gives me undefined:

```
function myRequest(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && xhr.contentType == "json") {
            console.log("Type", xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
            console.log("Text", xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("This is not a Json file");
        }
    };


    xhr.send();
}
```

The url I'm trying to get the data from is this : https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/bergen/dokart?

I really need some help figuring out why this is not working, thank you very much.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: What exactly gives you `undefined`?

Comment: It purely says undefined

Comment: The function has no return statement. It will always evaluate to `undefined`. Why is that a problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, because the question is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Set the expected responseType after the open method.
xhr.responseType = 'json';

Secondly, you should alter your conditions so that it checks for readyState === 4 /* finished */ and then condition the status to 200 or `else`. This os because the else condition will fire on readyState 2, 3 (or what not).

Try this:

```
function myRequest(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if ( xhr.status === 200 ) {
                console.log("Type", xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
                console.log("Text", xhr.response);
            } else {
                console.log("This is not a Json file");
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correct way get Response header in `if` condition, Use `xhr.getResponseHeader` to get Response header. So take a look in below code now It is working.

```
function myRequest(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type") || "";
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && contentType.indexOf("json") > -1) {
            console.log("Type", contentType);
            console.log("Text", xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("This is not a Json file");
        }
    };


    xhr.send();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) has no property `contentType`, so your code will not work as expected. Replace the content-type check in your if clause for `xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type')`, like below:

```
function myRequest(url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 && xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type') == "application/json") {
            console.log("Type", xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
            console.log("Text", xhr.responseText);
        } else {
            console.log("This is not a Json file");
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Check the image below. You will notice that while testing in the console, each statement logs the result of that statement, so you will see some 'undefined' in the console and that is normal. Check that when I run the function against a json api I'll get two 'This is not a json' because the `onreadystatechanged`is called multiple times, one for each xhr.readyState. Then, when xhr.readyState finally gets to 4, the console logs 'Type' and 'Text' as you wanted.

[image: sample_xmlhttprequest]

Comment: It gives another error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: @GabrielMatei — What do you mean "another error"? You never said anything about an error in the original question.

Comment: Sorry , that was a mistake from my part, it is not another error, it's just the undefined and that other one from my previous comment.

Comment: as others pointed out, if there's no return statement in your function it will return the default value of `undefined`, so that is expected. What is the problem with the code in my answer? I just tried against a JSON api and it worked fine (that is, it logged the type and text correctly)

Answer (score -1):

```js
function myRequest() {
    var url = 'https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/bergen/dokart';
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
        var contentType = this.getResponseHeader('content-type');
          if (contentType.includes('application/json')) {
            console.log("Text", xhr.responseText);
            console.log("json", JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
          } else {
           console.log("This is not a Json file", xhr);
          }
            
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

myRequest();
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't see your problem, but:

You can do it like this

```
function myRequest() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", 'https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/bergen/dokart');
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Read about http requests here: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp

Or you could do it just a simple way like this:

```
fetch('https://hotell.difi.no/api/json/bergen/dokart') 
.then((res) => {
   console.log(res.json());
})
```